# Print words from specific position in a list with suffix to each word

Tags: python

I have a list and would like to print all words after 4th position using python and each word after the 3rd position will be suffixed with ".com"

Example

```
my_list = ['apple', 'ball', 'cat', 'dog', 'egg', 'fish', 'rat']
```

From the above I would like to print the value from 'egg' onwards, i.e: egg.com, fish.com, rat.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```py
for i in my_list[3:]: 
    print(i + '.com')
```

That is it.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def get_words(lst, word):
    ' Returns string of words starting from a particular word in list lst '
    # Use lst.index to find index of word in list
    #     slice (i.e. lst[lst.index(word):] for sublist of words from word in list
    #     list comprehension to add '.com' to each word starting at index
    #     join to concatenate words
    if word in lst:
        return ', '.join([x + '.com' for x in lst[lst.index(word):]])
```

**Usage**

```
my_list = ['apple', 'ball', 'cat', 'dog', 'egg', 'fish', 'rat']

print(get_words(my_list, 'egg'))  # egg.com, fish.com, rat.com
print(get_words(my_list, 'dog'))  # dog.com, egg.com, fish.com, rat.com
print(get_words(my_list, 'pig'))  # None
```